# force output param to not be tinyint?

Tags: sql-server

I just inherited a stored procedure as part of a system for inserting a new user.
At the top, `@user_id` is declared as `INT OUTPUT` and at the bottom `SET @user_id = @@IDENTITY`, which always returns zero for some reason. If I do:

```
select @@IDENTITY
```

...I get something around '1872040'

If I do:

```
SET @user_id = 187300
```

...I get:

> Error converting data type int to smallint

I also get the same if I do:

```
SET @user_id = CAST(@@IDENITY as INT)...
```

It needs to be `SET @user_id = CAST(@@IDENITY as TINYINT)` or just`@user_id = @@IDENITY` for it to not give me errors. However, then it just returns null / 0.   So, I was googling around and couldn't really find an answer, is there a better way to force the output param to not be tinyint?  this is in ms sql.

Comment: You may need to post the sproc up for us to see - that sounds a bit odd to be honest! Plus, you probably want to be using SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproduced a scenario that can cause this problem. I think it could be not the sproc itself, but the way you're calling the sproc - specifically, the data type being specified for @user_id by the calling code.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @user_id SMALLINT -- THIS IS WRONG, SHOULD BE INT
EXECUTE YourSproc 'ValueA', @user_id OUTPUT
```

Once the IDENTITY value on the table exceeds the capacity of a SMALLINT, this would give you the conversion error.

So make sure you're specifying the correct datatype in the calling code.

Also, as per my comment, you probably want to be using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead of @@IDENTITY.

Comment: Hmm thanks! I checked the calling code (php) it is set as SQLINT4 which corresponds to BIGINT.. right?